# how do I add a missing bundle in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

When installing tools for AWS in Eclipse, I encountered the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software currently installed: Amazon SimpleDB Management 1.0.0.v201111161400 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v201111161400)
>   Missing requirement: Eclipse Data Tools Platform Amazon SimpleDB UI Plug-in 1.0.0.v201111161400 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.ui 1.0.0.v201111161400) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqlscrapbook 1.0.0' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: Amazon SimpleDB Management 1.0.0.v201111161400 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v201111161400)
>   To: com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.ui [1.0.0.v201111161400]

What is the problem here and how do I resolve it?  Sorry, but I am new to Eclipse and Java dev in general. Could the following message be the key?

> requires 'bundle org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqlscrapbook 1.0.0' but it could not be found

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found that the answer Jerinaw sourced from the AWS forum didn't work for me.  I had to do it a little different (Indigo Java EE IDE) :

Details:

1. Launch the new software installer in Eclipse (Help -> Install New Software...)
2. In the "Work with:" field fill in the url according to your Eclipse version (if you're using *indigo*, *kepler*, or *luna*, just replace *mars* with your version's name in the below url).

   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars

The address should already be in the "Work with:" drop-down.

3. Click on the check box next to "Database Development" (click next, accept license, click finish, should be prompted for restart).
4. Launch the new software installer and in the "work with:" field enter http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse
5. Select the packages you please and install

Comment: Worked with Kepler. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better answer:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=374353

Re: Installing AWS Java SDK Plugin for Eclipse -- issues
Posted by: Steven McGraw
Posted on: Aug 21, 2012 8:42 PM
 in response to: ZachM@AWS
        Reply
error , aws , java , eclipse , plugin , j2ee , indigo
As I have Indigo installed (IDE without EE), I first had to install the Data Tools Platform on top of Indigo to avoid seeing this error (as mentioned above).

Details: Launch the new software installer in Eclipse (Help -> Install New Software...)
Add on the DTP repository site (click 'Add' and I installed from this site: Link: http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates/ and name it something like "DTP")
As I wanted the latest version of DTP so I selected the DTP 1.10.0 Extender SDK (Includes source and JavaDocs) If you want to see quickly what versions of DTP exist, go here: Link: http://eclipse.org/datatools/downloads.php as ZachM pointed to above.

So that all worked for me, thanks ZachM.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if you install Eclipse for Java Developers, you may be missing some components.  Select "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" instead and you will not encounter this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You might also see the problem if you installed the version of Eclipse that comes packaged with the ADT bundle from the Android developer site. DavisRunning's answer for installing the database tools also helps in this case, except you might want to check with version of Eclipse  you have. Mine was packaged with Juno so my download site was http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno. After that just use the Amazon download site and the AWS toolkit should install as expected.